# Hitting multiple API in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I am new to iOS development, and I am facing a lot of trouble in calling API. I have created a page for a chatting app where I need to display top users of that particular app in a collection view cell through pagination. I also need to show another array of images in a hexagon above that collection view cell.

Thereby it is required for me to use two API in the same page. I have already used first URL for the collection view cell and its working fine. But am facing trouble with the second one. I have already applied the second URL but whenever am running the page, it crashes. Here is my code below:

```
@interface TattooSinglesScreen ()

@property(nonatomic,strong) NSURLConnection *connection;
@property NSMutableData *responseData;
@property NSMutableDictionary *responsedic;
@property NSMutableArray *arrname,*arrage,*arrcity,*arrdistance;

@end

@implementation TattooSinglesScreen{


    NSMutableData *_receivedData;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self callApi:@"http://tattoosingles.net/webservice/tattoosingles.php" param:@"id=578&call=0"];
    [self callApi:@"http://tattoosingles.net/webservice/eye.php" param:@"id=578"];




   // [self callApi:@"http://www.playmart.in/Api/GetMenu" param:@""];
    // [self callApi:@"http://tattoosingles.net/webservice/tattoosingles.php" param:@"id=578&call=0"];

   // [self createButton];
        _arrname=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

     //   _arrTopListImages=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        _backview.hidden=true;

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

      scrollView.delegate = self;
        scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.pagingEnabled=YES;


   // _arrTopListImages=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"docpanic.png",@"makani.png",nil];

  //  NSLog(@"array top Images %lu",(unsigned long)_arrTopListImages.count);
    int i;

       [scrollView setAlwaysBounceVertical:NO];
    for (i=0; i<[_arrTopListImages count]; i++)
    {

        _TopList_ImageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(((_TopList_ImageView.frame.size.width)*i)+10, 5,_TopList_ImageView.frame.size.width, _TopList_ImageView.frame.size.height)];
//        _TopList_ImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(1.570796325);

        _TopList_ImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[_arrTopListImages objectAtIndex:i]];



         _TopList_ImageView.layer.mask = [self ChangeShape:_TopList_ImageView];

        _TopList_ImageView.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
//        _TopList_ImageView.layer.borderWidth=4;
//        _TopList_ImageView.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
//        _TopList_ImageView.layer.masksToBounds=YES;

        [scrollView addSubview:_TopList_ImageView];
    }
    scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(_TopList_ImageView.frame.size.width*i+20, scrollView.frame.size.height);
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://tattoosingles.net/webservice/tattoosingles.php"];



    NSMutableURLRequest *request =[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:
                                   url];



    NSString *postData = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"id=578&call=0"];


    [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[postData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    _connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];


    _arrNum=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10",@"11",@"12",@"13",@"14",@"15",@"16",@"17",@"18",@"19",@"20",nil];

   // _arrImages= [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@", nil]
  //  NSLog(@"array num %lu",(unsigned long)_arrNum.count);

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];

    [singleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

}

-(void)callApi : (NSString *)url param:(NSString *)parameter{

NSMutableURLRequest *request =
[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *postString = parameter;

[request setValue:[NSString
                   stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postString length]]
forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-length"];

[request setHTTPBody:[postString
                      dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSURLConnection *con= [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];


}


- (void) handleSingleTap: (id) sender

{

    [_backview setHidden:YES];

}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[_responsedic valueForKey:@"name" ] count];

}


-(CAShapeLayer*)ChangeShape:(UIView*)view
{
    UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 80, 80, 80)];
    v.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];


    CGRect rect = v.frame;

    CAShapeLayer *hexagonMask = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    CAShapeLayer *hexagonBorder = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    hexagonBorder.frame = v.layer.bounds;
    UIBezierPath *hexagonPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    CGFloat sideWidth = 2 * ( 0.5 * rect.size.width / 2 );
    CGFloat lcolumn = ( rect.size.width - sideWidth ) / 2;
    CGFloat rcolumn = rect.size.width - lcolumn;
    CGFloat height = 0.866025 * rect.size.height;
    CGFloat y = (rect.size.height - height) / 2;
    CGFloat by = rect.size.height - y;
    CGFloat midy = rect.size.height / 2;
    CGFloat rightmost = rect.size.width;
    [hexagonPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(lcolumn, y)];
    [hexagonPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(rcolumn, y)];
    [hexagonPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(rightmost, midy)];
    [hexagonPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(rcolumn, by)];
    [hexagonPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(lcolumn, by)];
    [hexagonPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, midy)];
    [hexagonPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(lcolumn, y)];

    hexagonMask.path = hexagonPath.CGPath;
    hexagonBorder.path = hexagonPath.CGPath;
    hexagonBorder.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    hexagonBorder.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    hexagonBorder.lineWidth = 5;
    v.layer.mask = hexagonMask;
    [v.layer addSublayer:hexagonBorder];

    //    hexagonMask.path = path.CGPath;
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return hexagonMask;
}


- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";


     TattooSinglesCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
    cell.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    cell.layer.shadowPath = [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cell.bounds cornerRadius:cell.layer.cornerRadius] CGPath];

    UIImageView *imageview=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(6, 12, 50, 50)];
    imageview.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"hex64.png"];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imageview];

    UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 22, 23, 30)];
    // label.text=@"1";
    // label.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    for (int i=0; i<_arrNum.count;i++ )
    {
        //label=[[UILabel alloc]init];
        label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_arrNum objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];

      //  NSLog(@"LBL TEXT %@",label.text);

    }
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    label.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:20];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label];


    //    Code for showing text in a label in Collection cell view


    cell.lblName.text=[[[[[[_responsedic valueForKey:@"full_name"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]stringByAppendingString:@" "]stringByAppendingString:@"("]stringByAppendingString:[[_responsedic valueForKey:@"age"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]stringByAppendingString:@")"];

    cell.lblcity.text=[[[[[[_responsedic valueForKey:@"city"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]stringByAppendingString:@"("]stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",[[[_responsedic valueForKey:@"distance"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]floatValue]]]stringByAppendingString:@"km"]stringByAppendingString:@")"];


    //[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%00.02d", intValue]
//    cell.lbldistance.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.89",[[[_responsedic valueForKey:@"distance"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]intValue]];

        NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://tattoosingles.net/uploads/%@",[_arrname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
    [cell.profileimage sd_setImageWithURL:url ];
                        // placeholderImage:[UIImage sd_animatedGIFNamed:@"indicator"]];


    return cell;
}


-(CGSize) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat screenWidth = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
    CGFloat minSpace = 12; //Space that you want
    return  CGSizeMake((self.view.frame.size.width - minSpace) / 2-3 ,216 ); //Cell height is your collectionViewCell height.



}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"Did Receive Response %@", response);
    _responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    _receivedData=[[NSMutableData alloc] init];

}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data
{
    //NSLog(@"Did Receive Data %@", data);
    //NSLog(@"%@",data);
    [_responseData appendData:data];

    [_receivedData appendData:data];

 //   NSLog(@"priya%@",_responseData);

    //    NSError * error = nil;
    //    NSArray  *responseArray = [ NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData :_responseData options : 0 error :&error];
    //    NSLog(@"%@",responseArray);
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didFailWithError:(NSError*)error
{

    if (_receivedData == nil) {
        //  NSLog(@"Couldn't Fetched the Data");

    }else{

        NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_receivedData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];

        if (dic==nil) {


            UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Could not load the menu" message:@"Do You want to Try Again ?" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
            UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {

            }];
            [alert addAction:okAction];
            [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
        else{




           // [Model sharedInstance].arrayMenu = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

            NSArray *arrayData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[dic valueForKey:@"data"]];

            for (int i=0; i<[arrayData count]; i++) {

             //   [[Model sharedInstance].arrayMenu addObject:[arrayData objectAtIndex:i]];

            }
        }
    }











    NSLog(@"Did Fail");
    //    [_activityView stopAnimating];
    //    _activityView.hidden=YES;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];

    UIAlertView *balle =[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"NO INTERNET" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [balle show];
}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"Did Finish");



    NSError * error = nil;
    _responsedic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    NSLog(@"%@",_responsedic);

    _arrname=[_responsedic valueForKey:@"profile"];
    NSLog(@"%@",_arrname);
       /*
     #pragma mark - Navigation

     // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
     - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
     // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     }
     */
    [_profilecollectionview reloadData];

}
```

Currently my screen looks like this:

[image: Image 1]

But I need to show like this

[image: Image 2]

Comment: remove this in viewdidload `[self callApi:@"http://tattoosingles.net/webservice/eye.php" param:@"id=578"];` and add in after this `NSLog(@"Did Finish");`

Comment: not working sir :(

Comment: NSURLConnection is also deprecated in favor of NSURLSession so you probably wanna use that...

Answer (score 0):

please try to make separate file for your ViewController and web service Logic.
And never try to call the Webservices in viewDidLoad instead call in viewWillAppear.

Comment: What about the code?? Have i done any mistake beside calling the webservice in viewDidLoad?

Comment: comment first call and run, check it is working or not .

Comment: then there is the problem in second call. your web service might not be working. check that.

Comment: Am not getting it...thats why am asking here

Comment: your web service is not working. please look into that from backend.

Answer (score 0):

If you require to use second url data with first url data to display in collection view call First Webservice iv ViewWillapper and in response of first api call second api...May it works for you..

Comment: Hi..Do you get logic?How should you implement?

Answer (score 0):

Well, When you calling two API call at the same time with same function it might crash the application. You need use completion block for your API method.

1. Define the completion block

```
 typedef void(^myCompletion)(BOOL);
```

2. Replace your code

```
[self callApi:@"http://tattoosingles.net/webservice/tattoosingles.php" param:@"id=578&call=0" :^(BOOL finished)
     {
         if(finished){
             NSLog(@"success");
             [self callApi:@"http://tattoosingles.net/webservice/eye.php" param:@"id=578" :^(BOOL finished)
              {
                  if(finished){
                      NSLog(@"Finish");
                  }
              }];
         }
     }];
```

3. When your receive response you need set flag completion your block

```
-(void) callApi:(NSString *)url param:(NSString *)parameter :(myCompletion) compblock{
    //do stuff
    compblock(YES);
}
```

Hope it will help you!

Comment: Crash problem is resolved thanks to your code but image is still missing :(